# Using preg_match to accept @ too

Tags: php, preg-match

Having a tough time.. this should be easy for you NINJA's out there.

Here is part of my function:

```
  if (strlen($_POST['uname']) < 3 || strlen($_POST['uname']) > 30 || !preg_match("/^([0-9A-Za-z])+$/i", $_POST['uname']) || $uname != 2)
```

We would want to include email address too, but can't figure out how to include the "@" symbol too ??

THanks in advance!!

Comment: `filter_var()` would be way eaiser: e.g. `var_dump(filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));`

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks for the reply, would I just replace that with my preg_match ?

Comment: Yes you just can replace the `preg_match()` just make sure you don't accidentally delete the `!` :D So did it worked for you? (Should I put an answer?)

Comment: @Rizier123 See edits to my string / function, I will need to use that exact format! THanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If I understad what you want : !preg_match("/^([\W])+$/i" or maybe use posix :

```
<?php
$regex = '[[:punct:]]';

if (preg_match('/'.$regex.'/', 'somepas$', $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
?>
```

Comment: Updated my full string that I use in my function that I will need to replace, thanks! See edits above!